# How to check if a range of numbers supplied exist in a list? - Python

Tags: python

I have a rather cumbersome line of code:

```
s=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

if 1 in s or 2 in s or 3 in s or 4 in s or 5 in s or 6 in s or 7 in s or 8 in s or 9 in s:
    print("Yes, a number between 1-9 exists in list s)
```

Is there a better way than this? I want to check if any number exists between [1-9] within list s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `any()` and `range(1, 10)` to check whether a number is in `s`:

```
if any(x in s for x in range(1, 10)):
    print('yes')
```

This makes use of a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to avoid creating a whole list of values before passing that to `any()`.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `str()`, as `s` is a list of integers

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll have to get my head round generators when I come to them.

Comment: The top of the range is 9 according to the OP's requirement, though.

Comment: Yes, and range excludes the upper bound so 10 is not included.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Simeon Visser's answer, but only for small lists.

If you ever need to do anything like this with large lists, you should probably use set intersection like so:

```
data_to_test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

values = list(range(1, 10))

set_data = set(data_to_test)
set_values = set(values)

if set_data.intersection(set_values):
    print("yes")
```